# Group by Date and sum the count

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out this issue but unable to solve it.
I have an array of objects below and what I am trying to do is to group it by date and sum the count.

```js
var arr = [
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-19 10:00:00.0", Division: "PC    ", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-06-01 18:00:00.0", Division: "CONGSO", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-14 20:00:00.0", Division: "CUA5  ", Count: "9"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-28 14:00:00.0", Division: "HR    ", Count: "9"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-19 11:00:00.0", Division: "SERK  ", Count: "20"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 17:00:00.0", Division: "WWCBS ", Count: "5"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-13 08:00:00.0", Division: "ECEADM", Count: "3"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-27 09:00:00.0", Division: "BRIDGE", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-14 09:00:00.0", Division: "WFI   ", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-06-01 13:00:00.0", Division: null, Count: "156"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-20 16:00:00.0", Division: "BRIDGE", Count: "2"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 14:00:00.0", Division: "TQM   ", Count: "9"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 17:00:00.0", Division: "PHC   ", Count: "3"}
];
```

The expected output would be like below:

```js
var output = [
 {2020-05-13: 3},
 {2020-05-14: 10},
 {2020-05-19: 21},
 {2020-05-20: 2},
 {2020-05-22: 17},
 {2020-05-27: 1},
 {2020-05-28: 9},
 {2020-06-01: 157}
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your specific question?

Comment: I did try different ways but couldn't get logic to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a shorter route, you could evaluate the use of [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

The implementation would be something like:

```
var array = [
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-19 10:00:00.0", Division: "PC    ", Count: "1"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-06-01 18:00:00.0", Division: "CONGSO", Count: "1"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-14 20:00:00.0", Division: "CUA5  ", Count: "9"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-28 14:00:00.0", Division: "HR    ", Count: "9"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-19 11:00:00.0", Division: "SERK  ", Count: "20"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 17:00:00.0", Division: "WWCBS ", Count: "5"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-13 08:00:00.0", Division: "ECEADM", Count: "3"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-27 09:00:00.0", Division: "BRIDGE", Count: "1"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-14 09:00:00.0", Division: "WFI   ", Count: "1"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-06-01 13:00:00.0", Division: null, Count: "156"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-20 16:00:00.0", Division: "BRIDGE", Count: "2"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 14:00:00.0", Division: "TQM   ", Count: "9"},
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 17:00:00.0", Division: "PHC   ", Count: "3"}
];

const groupedByCaptureTime = lodash.groupBy(array, 'CaptureTime');
const countResult = lodash.sumBy(arr, 'Count');
```

I hope this has helped you.

Comment: Thanks @ljsb. In my current application, I am not using lodash at this moment but it is good to know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to store the dates that have already been added to the result array and their index in it. When looping over the array, check if the date is a key in the object and if it is not, add the entry to the array; otherwise, increment the count of the entry already in the array.

```js
var arr = [
  {CaptureTime: "2020-05-19 10:00:00.0", Division: "PC    ", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-06-01 18:00:00.0", Division: "CONGSO", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-14 20:00:00.0", Division: "CUA5  ", Count: "9"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-28 14:00:00.0", Division: "HR    ", Count: "9"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-19 11:00:00.0", Division: "SERK  ", Count: "20"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 17:00:00.0", Division: "WWCBS ", Count: "5"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-13 08:00:00.0", Division: "ECEADM", Count: "3"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-27 09:00:00.0", Division: "BRIDGE", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-14 09:00:00.0", Division: "WFI   ", Count: "1"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-06-01 13:00:00.0", Division: null, Count: "156"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-20 16:00:00.0", Division: "BRIDGE", Count: "2"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 14:00:00.0", Division: "TQM   ", Count: "9"},
{CaptureTime: "2020-05-22 17:00:00.0", Division: "PHC   ", Count: "3"}
];
const res = [];
const mapping = {};
arr.forEach(a=>{
    const date = a.CaptureTime.split(" ")[0];
    if(!(date in mapping)){
     mapping[date] = res.length;
        res.push({[date]: +a.Count})
    } else {
     res[mapping[date]][date] += +a.Count;
    }
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's what exactly I'm looking for. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @dsoumgit No problem.